# how to add an element to a list, which has been defined in the super method?

Tags: java

I need to overwrite one method in the parent class. The method in the subclass should add one variable to a list, which is initialized in a method of the parent class.

```
class A{ methodA(){ 
  ..logic 
  List l = new ArrayList(); 
  l.add(..) } ..logic }

class B extends A{
  methodB(){ 
  //need to add variable to l  and then call method A
   } }
```

is this possible?

Comment: Well `l` is scoped to your `methodA`, so you can't access it in `methodB`. It would make it a lot easier to help you if you'd write a [mcve] instead of pseudo-code, and *format* the code conventionally too.

Comment: create a method that add elements and call it from B by super.add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
class Parent {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i;

    public void setList() {
        i = 10;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            list.add(i);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void setList() {
        super.setList();
        list.add(i);
    }
}

public class OverrideSuperClassMethodByAddingTOList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c1 = new Child();
        c1.setList();
        System.out.println(c1.list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you have written your pseudocode seems to have a logic bomb. In methodB you state:

```
//need to add variable to l  and then call method A
```

But then when you call methodA, the list l is initialised. Why not have

```
private List l = new ArrayList();
```

in A with appropriate getter and setter and manipulate that?

Answer (score 1):

either make the `List l` public or create a method in A that adds to the list